# How to skip value for current category in foreach loop wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, foreach, categories

I want to create a list of categories where the current category gets a different layout. However, i cannot get the foreach working...

I tried to make the foreach skip (continue) when the $category equals $current_category. However, it doesnt skip but ouputs all the values anyway

```
  <?php
  $args = array(
     'orderby' => 'slug',
     'parent' => 0
  );
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  $current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
     if ($current_category == $category) {
     continue;
     }
     else{
     echo '<li class="categorieknop"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '' . '' . $category->description . '</a></li>';
     }
}
 ?>
```

Expected is not the output of the current category, however, it does output the current category...

Comment: You are not taking the category name into accout

Comment: right now, you are comparing a string to an object.

Comment: you could do `$currentObject = get_queried_object(); if($currentObject == $category){continue;}else {whatever}`

Comment: cool - might as well take this question down again, to keep SO from bloating ;)

Comment: Dont you want the points? you post the right answer, i give you the correct checkmark :)

Comment: nah it's cool. never really cared about the points :-D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @stender who pointed out that i was comparing an object to a string hereby the correct code:

```
  <?php
  $args = array(
     'orderby' => 'slug',
     'parent' => 0
  );
  $categories = get_categories( $args );
  $current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
     if ($current_category === $category->name) {
     echo '<li class="current categorieknop"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '' . '' . $category->description . '</a></li>';
     continue;
     }
     else{
     echo '<li class="categorieknop"><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $category->name . '' . '' . $category->description . '</a></li>';
     }
}
 ?>
```